# hooks call order and hooks dependency

Tags: routes, hooks, stream-wrappers

I try to implement `hook_menu()` in a module and the code inside of this hook depends on another hook implemented in the same module Example:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
   $streamwrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme('myscheme');
   if($streamwrapper !== false) {
      $directory = $streamwrapper->getDirectoryPath();
       .....
   }
}
```

and another hook function in the same (mymodule) module

```
function mymodule_stream_wrappers() {
  retunr array( 'myscheme' => array(...)
}
```

Apparently, `hook_stream_wrappers()` is called after `hook_menu()`, and `file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme()` returns `false` during module installation process.

So, the whole idea works because Drupla will call `hook_menu` eventually and by that time stream wrapper will be in place and ready, but it seems too unreliable, IMHO.

Anyway, **is it possible to control hooks order somehow**? Or is there a better way to achieve desired result - retrieve stream wrapper in hook_menu after is has been known by the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is actually the opposite of what you're thinking. A call to `file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme` triggers hook_stream_wrappers() if it hasn't been called already.

However, the problem is that the stream wrapper hook *was* already called before your module was enabled and the information from that is statically cached. So you need to clear the static cache to get your own stream wrapper:

```
drupal_static_reset('file_get_stream_wrappers');
```

Comment: Thanks Berdir!
Right to the point - the problem is because of cache, but the only way to do what I want (without Drupal patching) is to call `drupal_static_reset` right before I call for my wrapper. Look like `file_get_stream_wrappers` is implemented:

Comment: I miss my chance to edit previous comment sorry...

`file_get_stream_wrappers()` checks entire cache, regardless of schema and calls the modules hooks if it is not set.
    
Means that any cached wrapper disables hooks for all of the rest. The cache is almost for sure is populated by "public" and "private" and "Clear all caches" in admin does not help. And if I call `drupal_static_reset()` I will set other modules in the same trouble.

Comment: This is just a static cache which means that it rebuilt on every request. So this really should only happen while your module is being installed. So it should be safe to call drupal_static_reset() (you could do it in your hook_enable() to prevent it from running on every subsequent menu rebuild). Most static caches in drupal are pretty dump and need to be explicitly cleared if know that there is more up to date information.

Comment: It really happens during install only. Thanks for the hook_enable() idea!

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation, the function [`file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme/7) call another function that call the hook `hook_stream_wrappers`.

Logically your code should work.

I see here that you've a mistake in your `return`

```
function mymodule_stream_wrappers() {
  retunr array( 'myscheme' => array(...)
}
```

it may the cause of your problem.